# DateAdd return value is incorrect

Tags: vba

I know this may be a simple question, but I cannot figure this out. When running the debugger for VBA, the third argument on line 11 shows up as "9/13/2016" as expected, but start_d is "06/09/2016" for some reason???

I have tried setting start_d to both a string and Date object, both yield the same result. All I want is for start_d to be 7 days before the current date.

```
Sub addData(lastRow As Integer, lab() As String, c() As String, IP() As String, usage() As String, fName As String)
Dim reportWeek As Integer
Dim numWeeks As Integer
Dim monthWeek As Integer
Dim start_d As Date ' As String UPDATED
Dim thisYear As String
Dim thisMonth As String
Dim thisDay As String

' the reports run every monday
start_d = DateAdd("d", -7, Date)
'start_d = Format(start_d, "dd/mm/yyyy") UPDATED 

thisYear = year(start_d) 'year(CDate(start_d)) UPDATED
thisMonth = month(start_d) 'month(CDate(start_d)) UPDATED
thisDay = day(start_d) 'day(CDate(start_d)) UPDATED

reportWeek = weekNum
monthWeek = getWeekOfMonth(CDate(start_d))
numWeeks = weekCount(thisYear, thisMonth)

Debug.Print reportWeek & monthWeek & numWeeks & thisYear & thisMonth & thisDay
End Sub
```

Comment: change system date format to dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: there was no option for dd-mm-yyyy on my laptop, so I used dd-MM-yy. start_d is still incorrect: "06-09-2016". Why is it not even in the format of the system date...??

Comment: @HA560 I was able to customize it to the date you asked, it still comes up with "06-09-2016"

Comment: You're working with dates as strings. It's much safer to work with dates as Dates - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `start_d` to a `Date` type, and you can do away with the `Format` and `CDate` conversions:

```
Dim start_d As Date
```

Which gives you:

```
Sub addData()
Dim reportWeek As Integer
Dim numWeeks As Integer
Dim monthWeek As Integer
Dim start_d As Date
Dim thisYear As String
Dim thisMonth As String
Dim thisDay As String

' the reports run every monday
start_d = DateAdd("d", -7, Date)

thisYear = Year(start_d)
thisMonth = Month(start_d)
thisDay = Day(start_d)

reportWeek = WeekNum
monthWeek = getWeekOfMonth(start_d)
numWeeks = weekCount(thisYear, thisMonth)

Debug.Print reportWeek & monthWeek & numWeeks & thisYear & thisMonth & thisDay
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Seems you're still having issues - let's try with a Long to represent Date:

```
Sub addData()
Dim reportWeek As Integer
Dim numWeeks As Integer
Dim monthWeek As Integer
Dim start_d As Date
Dim thisYear As String
Dim thisMonth As String
Dim thisDay As String

Dim today As Long
today = Int(Now)

' the reports run every monday
start_d = DateAdd("d", -7, today)

thisYear = Year(start_d)
thisMonth = Month(start_d)
thisDay = Day(start_d)

reportWeek = WeekNum
'monthWeek = getWeekOfMonth(start_d)
'numWeeks = weekCount(thisYear, thisMonth)

Debug.Print reportWeek & monthWeek & numWeeks & thisYear & thisMonth & thisDay
End Sub
```

Comment: I attempted this, and did again just now for sanity's sake. I changed start_d to a Date object and rid my code of the cdate and format parts. Alas... still no go... :(

Comment: I've added an edit that uses a Long to preserve the date as a numeric. You shouldn't need to, but hopefully it works for you.

Comment: If it still doesn't work - you could try changing `start_d = DateAdd("d", -7, today)` to `start_d = Int(Now) - 7`

Comment: The `Date` function returns a `Variant`, the `Date` parameter in `DateAdd` accepts a `Variant` and the `DateAdd` function returns a `Variant`. That leaves room for your system to interpret the date according to regional/system settings. By using a numeric expression/`Long` to reflect the date, you take away any ambiguity.

Comment: I understand. Thank you soooo much!

Comment: Well, I DON'T understand, but after reading this I will forever use Date where tempted to use Double, and use Long for the interval in DateAdd.  Just now, I was using DateAdd to 'add'  -1 (hour) to a Date.  The value did not change.  I changed any Doubles to Date, change -1 to -1#, and the thing finally 'worked'.  I don't understand why, and I'm gonna quit trying to figure it out...